# Having trouble with Canvas

Tags: html, canvas

Coding noob here. I have myself a html page in my ASP.NET framework project. I have a variable `c` which is the canvas. I have made function calls to the canvas without a problem....  when I add another element to the page however the canvas gets pushed down lower on the page instead of being behind it. I feel like I have looked everywhere but I cant seem to find an answer to this issue.

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: black; opacity:.5; color:white;">
    <h1>testing</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `float absolute` in your style? https://jsfiddle.net/y37wcdg5/

Comment: @Canvas I appreciate that. It still moved to the bottom when i tried to apply that solution... reason says what you did should definitely work for some reason it just got pushed to the bottom regardless  :( again thanks for answering :)